# Can an individual act as an Admin while not counting as a user?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

The G Suite Basic Flexible Plan requires payment per user.  Is it possible to be an admin WITHOUT being a user?

Basically, as IT we only want access to help control billing and maintain users, but we don't want or need access to the documents themselves. Is it possible to be an admin without being counted as a "user"?

Any thoughts/knowledge about how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to be an admin without being a user as it's necessary to be an user to access the G Suite admin panel to manage the organization settings.

You could confirm this with the G Suite Sales team.